# How to implement syntax coloring in a JFace SourceViewer using PresentationReconciler?

Tags: swt, syntax-highlighting, text-editor, jface

I am trying to build a standalone Editor for C Language using SWT/JFace. I have used the `SourceViewer` for the editor part. But I am getting problem in implementing the syntax highlighting. I have done the following:

```java
public IPresentationReconciler getPresentationReconciler(ISourceViewer sourceViewer) 
{   
    if(reconciler!=null)
        return reconciler;
    reconciler =new PresentationReconciler();

    DefaultDamagerRepairer dr=new DefaultDamagerRepairer(getMultiScanner());
    reconciler.setDamager(dr, MyPartitionerScanner.MULTILINE_COMMENT);
    reconciler.setRepairer(dr, MyPartitionerScanner.MULTILINE_COMMENT);
    ...
    ... 
    return reconciler;
}
```

I have the above code in the my `SourceViewerConfiguration`. But nothing is happening in the editor.

Comment: That is just a small part of what is required. What are you using for the Scanner? Is the scanner producing IToken objects? Are you returned TextAttribute objects for the IToken data? Is your partition scanner identifying multi-line comments properly? You have only defined  a damager repairer for comments so nothing will be done for the rest of the document.

Comment: I am using `RuleBasedScanner` for scanner.

Comment: So far i have only defined damager repairer for comments, but even that is not working. The scanner is doing every thing given in [link]http://www.realsolve.co.uk/site/tech/jface-text.php .